# How to replace from null value empty string in java?

Tags: java

I'm getting the `null` values from DB, but I need to display the empty string `""` instead.

For example, I have to append four values to display in the single cell of a Excel sheet like below:

```
sheet.addCell(new Label(4, currentRow, a.getPar()+" "+a.getO()+" "+a.getPar()));
```

How to achieve the expected result (the replacement) in Java?

Comment: Please post some of your code...

Comment: can you elaborate your problem? and some code snippet on what you talking about?

Comment: Can you clarify?  If you're trying to print a null value and you want it to be displayed as an empty space, then check if the string is null, and if it is, display an empty space.

Comment: you could use Apache commons `StringUtils` for this: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#defaultString%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: Try [com.google.common.base.Strings.nullToEmpty()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Strings.html#nullToEmpty(java.lang.String))

Comment: how is this not a question? If you want to avoid null checking and have to deal with legacy APIs doing something like `Strings.nullToEmpty(s)` makes things clearer and better rather than cluttering the code with ternaries.

Comment: All good answers are here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21936503/get-empty-string-when-null

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use the ternary opperator:

```
System.out.println("My string is: " + ((string == null) ? "" : string));
```

In case you are not familiar with it, it reads "Is string null? If it is, then 'return' en empty string, else 'return' string". I say 'return' because you can consider `((string == null) ? "" : string)` as a function that returns a `String`.

You can replace the empty string with any other `String` of course.

Comment: I need ti check the null value for four string at time and display into excel sheet .

Comment: Replace `string` with `a.getParan()` and `a.getO()` maybe?

Comment: Applicable to JSP expression as well.

Answer (score 15):

If I understand correctly,  you need this

```
public static String replaceNull(String input) {
  return input == null ? "" : input;
}
```

and the use it where ever you need it like

```
sheet.addCell(new Label(4,currentRow, replaceNull(a.getParan())+" "+replaceNull(a.getO())+" "+replaceNull(a.getParan())));
```

Hope this helps