# Get empty string when null

Tags: java, guava

I want to get string values of my fields (they can be type of long string or any object),

if a field is null then it should return empty string, I did this with guava;

```
nullToEmpty(String.valueOf(gearBox))
nullToEmpty(String.valueOf(id))
...
```

But this returns null if gearbox is null! Not empty string because valueOf methdod returns string "null" which leads to errors.

Any Ideas?

EDIt: there are 100s fields I look for something easy to implement

Answer (score 254, accepted):

You can use [`Objects.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#toString%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) (standard in Java 7):

```
Objects.toString(gearBox, "")

Objects.toString(id, "")
```

---

From the linked documentation:

> `public static String toString(Object o, String nullDefault)`
>
> > Returns the result of calling `toString` on the first argument if the first argument is not null and returns the second argument otherwise.
> >
> > **Parameters:**
> >      `o` - an object
> >      `nullDefault` - string to return if the first argument is `null`
> >
> > **Returns:**
> >       the result of calling `toString` on the first argument if it is not `null` and the second argument otherwise.
> >
> > **See Also:**
> >       [`toString(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: @Spring You should consider upgrading, especially with Java 8 coming out soon. In any case, I'll leave this answer in case it can be helpful for future visitors.

Comment: Downvoter: please leave a comment. I would like to know what is wrong with my answer, and a downvote alone doesn't tell me.

Comment: NIce. I suggest `Objects.toString(id, "").trim()`

Comment: why it requires > API 19... its a simple check. i guess i have to write that my self

Comment: The risk is that u r losing the type of your string. It is currently a String but if it will change to a different type in the future he compiler won't protect u

Answer (score 71):

For java 8 you can use Optional approach:

```
Optional.ofNullable(gearBox).orElse("");
Optional.ofNullable(id).orElse("");
```

Comment: if id is not a string, it seems that the second line code cannot work

Comment: This does two method calls and allocates a new object and immediately discards it. This is not an improvement over the simple `gearBox == null ? "" : gearBox`. A single method call like `StringUtils.defaultString` is more JIT friendly.

Comment: @Vroo if you don't want the discard then the `orElseGet` can be use instead

Comment: @FedericoPiazza That's not an improvement. First, `orElseGet` takes a delegate so now I have ***three*** method calls. Second, an `Optional` object still gets created and then discarded.

Answer (score 38):

If you don't mind using Apache commons, they have a [`StringUtils.defaultString(String str)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#defaultString%28java.lang.String%29) that does this.

> *Returns either the passed in String, or if the String is null, an empty String ("").*

If you also want to get rid of `"null"`, you can do:

```
StringUtils.defaultString(str).replaceAll("^null$", "")
```

or to ignore case:

```
StringUtils.defaultString(str).replaceAll("^(?i)null$", "")
```

Comment: what if string is string "null"? thats my problem

Comment: @Spring: Updated to take care of that case too.

Comment: `StringUtils.defaultString` already checks for null. So the `replaceAll` is only changes the string is when it's a literal `"null"`, which is not what was asked for. Here's the source: `public static String defaultString(String str) { return str == null ? "" : str; }`

Comment: I believe the first comment concerned the literal string `"null"`

Answer (score 23):

If alternative way, **Guava** provides `Strings.nullToEmpty(String)`.

**Source code**

```
String str = null;
str = Strings.nullToEmpty(str);
System.out.println("String length : " + str.length());
```

**Result**

```
0
```

Answer (score 13):

`StringUtils.defaultString(String str)` Returns either the passed in String, or if the String is null, an empty String ("").

Example from java doc

> `StringUtils.defaultString(null)`  will return `""`
> `StringUtils.defaultString("")`    will return `""`
> `StringUtils.defaultString("bat")` will return `"bat"`

Answer (score 10):

Use an inline null check

```
gearBox == null ? "" : String.valueOf(gearBox);
```

Comment: Two seconds too fast!

Comment: @Samhain there are 100s fields I look for something easy to implkement

Answer (score 6):

Since you're using guava:

```
Objects.firstNonNull(gearBox, "").toString();
```

Comment: from guava 18 you need to use `MoreObjects.firstNonNull`

Answer (score 6):

In Java 9+ use : Objects.requireNonNullElse (obj, defaultObj) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNullElse-T-T-

```
//-- returns empty string if obj is null
Objects.requireNonNullElse (obj, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick: `"" + gearBox`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).