# Pad NULL Object with Empty String in its toString Result

Tags: java

I'm looking for a quick way, maybe in Apache StringUtils or another library, to pad the result of a NULL object with a specified char/str (maybe an empty string, ""). Otherwise, the object's toString() should work as normal.

Does there exist a method like that already? Apache's leftPad/rightPad don't change NULLs, they pad spaces.

e.g.

```
Integer getIntg1();
Integer getIntg2();
// etc.

System.out.println ("Intg1: " + pad(getIntg1, "") + //...  );
```

Comment: Apache's commons-lang has an ObjectUtils.toString(Object) that will do exactly that. [Javadoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils.html#toString(java.lang.Object))

Comment: take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16793361/32090

Comment: Could you define what you mean by "padding a null object with an empty string"? Example input and output would help.

Comment: It sounds like you mean replace instead of pad.